# how to view the specific number of rows in database using JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm working on a bus reservation project
In this code the user needs to input the details of the pickup and drop location and the code should display all the buses that cover those locations.. I have used

```
ResultSet rs= ps.executeQuery();
         while(rs.next()) {

                System.out.println(rs.getString(1)+"\t"+rs.getString(2)+"\t"+rs.getString(3)+"\t"+rs.getString(4)+"\t"+rs.getInt(5)+"\t"+rs.getInt(6));

         }
```

But it is displaying the first row and not all the other rows that have the same data.I want  the details of all the buses that cover the same location. So guys please help me.

In my database there are 2 buses (sj and neeta ) that cover those locations so it should display the details of all of them , but it just display the first  bus details i.e. sj and and not the other bus

My code is given below.

```
 static void Search(){
     Scanner s= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter the details : ");
       System.out.println("FROM:");
       String from=s.nextLine();
       System.out.println("TO:");
       String to=s.nextLine();
       System.out.println("TYPE: \n 1 for AC\n2 for non AC");
        String type=s.next();

    try {
        // step 1: load the driver
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
         // step 3: prepare statement
         try ( // step 2: create connection
                 Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sparsh?characterEncoding=UTF-8&useSSL=false","root","soccerplayers12")) {
             // step 3: prepare statement
             PreparedStatement ps =
                     (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("select * from busdetails where arrival=? and arrivaldest=? and type=?  ");
             ps.setString(1, from);
             ps.setString(2, to);
             ps.setString(3, type);
             // step 4: execute query
             ResultSet rs= ps.executeQuery();
             while(rs.next()) {

                    System.out.println(rs.getString(1)+"\t"+rs.getString(2)+"\t"+rs.getString(3)+"\t"+rs.getString(4)+"\t"+rs.getInt(5)+"\t"+rs.getInt(6));

             }

             // close connection
         }
                   }


    catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

   }
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Do you need help getting JDBC to work, do you need help writing a query, or both?

Comment: Have you executed this query on mysql editor and it shows two records?

Comment: I need help writing the query

Answer (score 1):

Using Query object you can fetch the specific records how much you want

```
query.setFirstResult(10);
query.setMaxResults(5);
```

It will return the records from 10 to 15.

From where you want set the `firstResult`.

How many you want from that set the `maxResults`

Comment: so all the records from 10 to 15 will be displayed?

Comment: You have to dynamically pass the firstResult value. It will fetch from the index to max you want